# Externalizing strings in plugin.xml for Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I externalize strings in my Eclipse plugin's plugin.xml?

Right-clicking on the plugin project > PDE Tools > Externalize Strings does not show up my plugin.

I'm trying to do this manually now. I added entries in plugin.properties and replaced the equivalent string in plugin.xml with a % sign followed by the string key. But that does not seem to work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally figured out how to manually externalize the plugin.

Eclipse, it turns out, externalizes plugin.xml this way:

- In the plugin manifest (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF), add the following line

  ```
  Bundle-Localization: plugin
  ```

  where you intend to store the externalized strings in a file called "plugin.properties" (Turns out this was the missing piece).
- Add the externalized string key-value pairs in plugin.properties.
- Replace the actual strings in plugin.xml with the keys from plugin.properties (prefixed with %).

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. +1. I have added some links related to that "Bundle-Localization" issue in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If your working set have plugin projects in it, the [**Externalize Strings** wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/pde_actions/externalize_strings.htm) to help externalize strings in your Manifest and plugin.xml files should be available.
Externalizing manifest files extracts translatable strings and stores them in a properties file for multi-language support.

The wizard is available **under the PDE Tools menu in the context menu of a PDE project's MANIFEST.MF or plugin.xml files**.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/images/pde_actions/externalize_strings_selection.png))</sub>

Be aware that there were some bugs related to [detecting all non-externalized attributes/values of the `<extension-point>` and `<extension>` elements](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=246788), or [showing up un-externalized names of extension(-point)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=252329), which are only solved in 3.4 or very recent 3.5M4.

However, if the "Externalize Strings" menu does not show up at all on your plugin projects, may be its "**[project nature](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_natures.htm)**" is corrupted somehow, may be your former Java project is [not properly converted to a PDE project](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_natures.htm) ?

So two suggestions:

- try with a fresh install of an eclipse3.5M4
- import your plugin project and check its nature

And then tell us if that menu is still unavailable.

---

As you mention [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644848/externalizing-strings-in-plugin-xml-for-eclipse-plugin/644963#644963), the externalization process is declared by the string

```
Bundle-Localization: plugin
```

in the MANIFEST.MF file, as mentioned in [this message](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg44094.html).

A [bug has been created](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=198866), but:

- The localization is not something specific to PDE but instead the OSGI specification
- that line is not always in the MANIFEST:

  > Prior to 3.3, we created all our manifests by creating a plugin.xml and then
  >   converting it.  The converter always added "Bundle-Localization: plugin" to the
  >   Manifest, since that is the default location if the plug-in has no Manifest.
  >   If a plug-in had no translations files, this header was unnecessary bloat.
  >   In 3.3, we created plug-in projects by creating Manifest directly, which means we
  >   decided to create only the headers necessary for project creation.
- it is likely to be an issue for those that have created bundles with
  externalization < 3.2, and then not being able to see them when running in 3.3.

Comment: For some reason, the Externalize String wizard shows up other plugins but not the required plugin. I did manage to fix the problem though. I've added it as a new answer here.

Comment: +1 For a complete solution that I didn't know that existed.  I normally internationalized all these strings by hand.

Comment: Thanks Nocturne for the post. Along with the changes which you mentioned in your post I would like to add one more line. While exporting the plug-in jar, do make the entry of plugin.properties in the build.properties file.