# How can I pass arguments to an extension point constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse calls the default (zero-argument) constructor when instantiating an extension point. I want to provide some arguments. I found a recommendation to use `IExecutableExtension#setInitializationData` but that appears to require specifying the argument values statically in XML. I need them to be dynamic. Another recommendation was to implement `IExecutableExtensionFactory` but that seems heavy handed. (The interface also seems pointless, as all it contains is a `create()` method.) I could add a method to set the values after creation but my class won't work correctly without them and they shouldn't be changed after creation, so forcing them to be provided at object creation time is preferable. This can't be a unique situation. What's the standard way of handling this?

Answer (score -1):

If the arguments need to be "dynamic," where would they come from? How would Eclipse know what values to use? Extension point objects are created when the plugin is activated, so there is not much context available at that point.

I think the best option for you is to use `IExecutableExtensionFactory` after all. Your factory can implement `IExecutableExtension` to receive the XML configuration data and then be coded to create the objects based on that and any other context you can make available to it.

Depending on your needs, you could use [Dynamic String Substitution Variables](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_variables_dynamicVariables.html) to insert certain context into your factory. See also [Externalizing strings in plugin.xml for Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644848/externalizing-strings-in-plugin-xml-for-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: By "dynamic" I mean "not known until runtime." I need a way to pass them as arguments. A varargs `createExecutableExtension(String propertyName, Object... arguments)` method would work well for my situation if such a method existed.