# How to set dynamic value like el in eclipse properties dialog?

Tags: eclipse

I would like to set variable  for specific parameter in eclipse project properties dialog.  Can I set parameter value like '${VERSION}' in project properties dialog (ex google app engine plugin) ?

Is there any way to set parameter values of plugin page and config files (xxx.xml) globally? even set parameter values of plugin page without open it

Comment: This depends on the particular property page and the plugin that provides the page. I don't know what the Google app engine plugin supports.

Comment: Is there any way to set parameter values of plugin page and config files (xxx.xml) globally?  even set parameter values of plugin page without open it..

Comment: Could you add more details on what you are trying to achieve?
What type of project are you working with/creating?
Which settings do you wish to externalize?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something along these lines:

[Externalizing strings in plugin.xml for Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644848/externalizing-strings-in-plugin-xml-for-eclipse-plugin)

With string externalization you can have strings in your Manifest and `plugin.xml` externalized to a `plugin.properties` file.

For example, you can have

```
version=1.5
```

in the `plugin.properties` and use

```
%version
```

as the version number in your Manifest.